# guestunmount: can't cd into a dir, but the permissions are ok

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, loop-device, fuse

Dir created inside a loop fs denies access, but has correct permissions.

init.sh - creates an fs image and mounts it (user and group ids are 1000):

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p out-dir
dd if=/dev/zero of=out-dir.img bs=1024 count=125
/sbin/mkfs.ext4 out-dir.img

guestmount -o uid=$(id -u) -o gid=$(id -g) -a out-dir.img -m/dev/sda out-dir
```

create.sh - creates a dir and does `cd`:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -m 700 out-dir/test
cd out-dir/test
```

The `cd` gives:

```
./create.sh: line 4: cd: out-dir/test: Permission denied
```

Then, `ls -lan out-dir`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 1000 1000  1024 Mar 21 15:27 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 1000 1000  4096 Mar 21 15:27 ..
drwx------ 2 1000 1000 12288 Mar 21 15:27 lost+found
drwx------ 2 1000 1000  1024 Mar 21 15:27 test
```

How to establish the correct mapping?

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you don't use a script but execute the steps one-by-one?

Comment: @Philippos, yes, verified that it happens when executing one-by-one. Also found an option to enable the permissions checking (looks like it's disabled by default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the option: `-o default_permissions`.

`guestmount --fuse-help`:

```
...
-o default_permissions enable permission checking by kernel
```